# Sum all values found in a text file and store them using Array_count_values in php

Tags: php, arrays, file, text, words

well, im a newbie in php, so i was making a program that counts words from a specific text file.
This is my text file:

```
Hello Hello Hello Hello
Hello Word array sum
Hello Find
```

This is my code (php:

```
/*Open file*/
$handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');

/*read all lines*/
while (! feof($handle)) {
$line = fgets($handle);

/*using array_count_values with str_word_count to count words*/
$result=       (array_count_values(str_word_count(strip_tags(strtoupper($line)), 1)));

/*sort array*/
arsort($result);

/*show the first ten positions and print array*/
$top10words2 = array_slice($result, 0, 10);
print "<pre>";
print_r ($top10words2);
print "</pre>";
}
fclose($handle);
```

but my output is like this:

```
Array{
[Hello] => 4
}
Array{
[Hello] => 1
[Word] => 1
[array] => 1
[sum] => 1
}
Array{
[Hello] => 1
[Find] => 1
}
```

I need the output to be like this:

```
Array{
[Hello] => 6
[Word] => 1
[array] => 1
[sum] => 1
[find] => 1
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: Of course you get that kind of output when you operate on each line separately, and don't do anything to merge the new count with those of the previous line. Just use file_get_contents to get the whole file content as one string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the `file_get_contents()` answer from [Ayaou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293044/ayaou), however for very large files you may need to do it as you've started. You want to build the array of words in the loop and then *count*, *sort* and *slice* afterward:

```
$result = array();
while(!feof($handle)) {
    $line = fgets($handle);
    $result = array_merge($result, str_word_count(strip_tags(strtoupper($line)), 1));
}
$result = array_count_values($result);
arsort($result);
$top10words2 = array_slice($result, 0, 10);
```

Comment: (disregard comment; didn't look closely enough at your code)

Comment: @ethan OK, I did't see it anyway ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `file_get_contents` instead

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
/* using array_count_values with str_word_count to count words */
$result = (array_count_values(str_word_count(strip_tags(strtoupper($fileContent)), 1)));
/* sort array */
arsort($result);
/* show the first ten positions and print array */
$top10words2 = array_slice($result, 0, 10);
print "<pre>";
print_r($top10words2);
print "</pre>";
```

Here is the output :

```
Array
(
    [HELLO] => 6
    [FIND] => 1
    [SUM] => 1
    [ARRAY] => 1
    [WORD] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything to combine the word counts that you calculate on each line.  By setting `$result = array_count_values(...)` you're abolishing the results from the previous loop.  Additionally, because you're performing your splice and dump from within the loop, you're never acting upon the full result set, and thus are never getting a real idea about what are the top 10 most used words.

Your code needs two changes:

1. Combine the counts from each line into a single array.
2. Wait until you're finished processing the file before looking at the
   results.

Using `file_get_contents()` will work, but depending on how large the file is that you're processing, this can cause memory limit errors.  A solution that utilizes your initial method would look like this:

```
$results = [];
while (!feof($handle)) {
  $line = fgets($handle);
  $line_results = array_count_values(str_word_count(strip_tags(strtoupper($line)), 1));
  foreach ($line_results as $word => $count) {
    if (isset($results[$word])) {
      $results[$word] += $count;
    }
    else {
      $results[$word] = $count;
    }
  }
}

arsort($results);
// etc...
```